# Do magic weapons have a slot for the purpose of Eidolons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, eidolon

According to pathfinder, Eidolons may use magic items, but share slots with the summoner. So if you put 2 rings on your eidolon your summoner can use 0 rings since the Eidolon used up both of your ring slots.
Slotless magic items are a thing that exists, such as Ioun stones.

This raises the question, is a magical sword and magical shield using the hand slots, or are they slotless items that physically require a hand to use.

If they use a hand slot, then the eidolon using a sword and shield would mean your summoner cannot be armed with their own magic sword and shield.
If they are slotless items that physically require a hand to wield, then both the summoner and the eidolon can use magic sword and shield at once. (or some other more optimal weapon).

This question also applies to 4 armed monsters who are often depicted wielding 4 swords at once. Since if those are magical slots then only 2 of the swords may be magical. Similar to how you may wear as many rings as you want, but only 2 rings may be magical.

Comment: I don't feel like your last paragraph is necessary; it should either be its own question or simply removed. It has nothing to do with Eidolons.

Comment: Its the same question though with the same answer. I guess you could change the title to "Do magic weapons have a slot for the purpose of Eidolons or 4 arms"? The question is about magic item rules rather than eidolon rules, eidolons are only a situation where it is relevant.

Comment: It might not have been, is what I'm getting at. If you're not asking about Eidolons (which have special, specific rules in regards to magic items) then they shouldn't be your primary point. It's in the title. That disuades people who are interested in, say, rules about [Kasatha](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/more-races/advanced-races-11-20-rp/kasatha-20-rp/) from checking/answering this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Magic Weapons usually do not occupy a magic item slot.

Magic Weapons [usually list](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/mage-s-crossbow/) "Slot none" for their slot, or [simply lack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/javelin-of-lightning/) any mention of a slot.

However, there are [some](https://aonprd.com/MagicWeaponsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Nightpiercer) that do occupy a slot when wielded, and thus would limit both you and your eidolon when wielded.